# How to run thread from push button?

Tags: qt

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "myobject.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    QThread cThread;
    MyObject cObject;
    cObject.doSetup(cThread);
    cObject.moveToThread(&cThread);
    // cThread.start();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    // cThread.start();
}
```

I'm trying to start the thread on on_pushButton_clicked(). In order to do this, I would have to pass cThread to mainwindow through an argument, right? I just want someone to confirm to make sure I'm doing it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like one way to do that. The other one would be to connect signal `clicked()` of button to thread's slot `start(Priority)` in your application which will be nicer and shorter.

Comment: The problem is that if I do it that way, then the user might be able to start multiple threads (I have an if statement to check for an alreadyStarted boolean). Any ideas?

Comment: Then your first approach is correct. Anyway, if it is binary state you can use checkbutton to get rid of your check.

Comment: By checkbutton, you mean checkbox? Or do you mean to somehow disable the button when clicked?

Comment: Disabling button will not reduce lines of code. I was thinking about checkbutton.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by checkbutton and I can't find it in the docs or on google.

Comment: Wait. I have an idea. I'll just disable the GUI's push button in the first line of the thread. Huzzah!